# C++ , function pointer exception error

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, function-pointers, c++17

I get "error: exception specifications are not allowed beyond a single level of indirection" with the following code. Please point me to the part of standard that says that it is not allowed. I want to be sure that it is really required by the language or just compiler specific error. If it is from language specification, what motivates this rule? I am using clang 3.8.0.

```
  int main()
    {
        void (**fp)() throw() ;
    }
```

Comment: "Please point me to a reference book /spec that says that it is not allowed." - standard?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan  I should have used "standard" in place of "spec". Anyone, please feel free to edit the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said:

> Please point me to a reference book /spec that says that it is not allowed. I want to be sure that it is really required by the language or just compiler specific error.

With

```
void (**fp)() throw() ;
```

you are trying to specify an *exception-specification* in the declaration of a pointer to a function pointer. That is not allowed by the standard. *Exception-specification* is allowed only for a limited set of declarations.

From https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/except.spec#2 (emphasis mine):

> An exception-specification shall appear only on a **function declarator for a function type**, **pointer to function type**, **reference to function type**, or **pointer to member function type that is the top-level type of a declaration or definition, or on such a type appearing as a parameter or return type in a function declarator**. An exception-specification shall not appear in a `typedef` declaration or *alias-declaration*. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
>  void f() throw(int);                    // OK
>  void (*fp)() throw (int);               // OK
>  void g(void pfa() throw(int));          // OK
>  typedef int (*pf)() throw(int);         // ill-formed
> ```
>
> — *end example* ] A type denoted in an *exception-specification* shall not denote an incomplete type. A type denoted in an *exception-specification* shall not denote a pointer or reference to an incomplete type, other than `void*`, `const void*`, `volatile void*`, or `const volatile void*`. A type *cv* `T`, “array of `T`”, or “function returning `T`” denoted in an *exception-specification* is adjusted to type `T`, “pointer to `T`”, or “pointer to function returning `T`”, respectively.

---

You asked:

> If it is from language specification, what motivates this rule?

I don't have an answer to that.